# csv file management in c++ (specifically setting headers and the values that each header will have respectively)

Tags: c++, csv

So I'll post my code and then ask my doubts below that, this is not a homework, I'm practicing something my cousin's old homework, so please chill on the not helping you because it's homework.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Loan{
 public:
  Loan();
  float principle;
  float months;
  float interest;
  float monthly_payments();
  float accrued();
  float remaining_bal();
};

float Loan::monthly_payments() {
  float payment;
  float j = interest/12;
  payment = j * principle /(1 - pow((1 + j), -1 * months));
  return payment;
}
Loan::Loan() {

}
float Loan::accrued() {
  float j = interest/12;
  float accrued = j*principle;
  return accrued ;
}
float Loan::remaining_bal() {
  float x = monthly_payments();
  float y = accrued();
  float remaining = principle - x + y;
  return remaining;
}

int main() {
  char filename[16]; //this will allow the file name be 16 in length
  cout << "Enter the name of an existing file: ";
  cin.getline (filename,16);

  cout << "\nThe name of your file is: " << filename << endl;

  ofstream myFile; // this will allow for file to be saved
  myFile.open (filename); // open file named: myFile

  if( myFile.good() )
    cout << "\nFile open is OK \n";
  else
    cout << "\nfile open FAILED \n";

  Loan l1;
  cout<<"Enter principle, months and interest rate"<<endl;
  cin>>l1.principle>>l1.months>>l1.interest;
  float x = l1.principle;
  float y = l1.months;
  float z = l1.interest;
  float accrued = l1.accrued();
  float monthly = l1.monthly_payments();
  float remaining = l1.remaining_bal();

  while (remaining > 0){
    myFile<<"month"<<"beginning balance"<<"monthly interest"<<"accrued interest"<<"final balance";

  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is what I have till now, now I want the columns as above and add the values to each of them separately in the form of a csv file, the tricky part is that these values are getting updated at each iteration, so I'm stuck on how to go about from here. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: there is no "not helping because it is homework", there is "not bothering to help because asker shows zero effort" and thats often the case for homework, but there is nothing wrong with homework by itself. So please chill on that :P

Comment: ***//this will allow the file name be 16 in length*** You need to include the null terminator so it will allow the file name to be 15 characters total + null terminator.

Comment: The biggest thing I see is that you need to do your calculations in the loop. Not before the loop. Your while loop is infinite because the variables don't change after they were set ( which happened before the while loop).

Comment: okay guys sorry for the chill comment, can u help me out on this tho

Answer (score 0):

You made some mistakes in your formulas.

To get the values for the next month, you need to calculate the values for the new month (based on the current) and then continue with those.

Unfortunately you have, in my humble opinion, also design problems in your struct or general approach. But I kept you original design as much as I could. Please try to refactor.

I corrected the formulas.

And, I added the values for the loop. These consist now on some calculations to get the current values for this month. Then we take the remaining balance and put it as current balance. Then we continue to run the loop.

I do additionally some accumulations for statistical purposes.

Please try it, and enter as filename something with the extension ".csv". Then you can open the file afterwords with Excel. And you will see your table. Of course you can also open with notepad++.

I updated also some programming style issues.

Please see

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

class Loan {
public:
    Loan() {}
    long double principal;
    long double months;
    long double interest;
    long double monthlyPayment();
    long double accrued(long double currentBalance);
    long double remainingBalance(long double currentBalance);
};

inline long double Loan::monthlyPayment() {
    const long double interestPerMonth = interest / 100.0 / 12.0;
    const long double temp = std::pow((1.0 + interestPerMonth), months);
    return principal / ((temp - 1) / (interestPerMonth * temp));
}

long double Loan::accrued(long double currentBalance) {
    long double j = interest / 12 / 100;
    long double accrued = j * currentBalance;
    return accrued;
}
long double Loan::remainingBalance(long double currentBalance) {
    long double x = monthlyPayment();
    long double y = accrued(currentBalance);
    long double remaining = currentBalance - x + y;
    return remaining;
}

int main() {

    // Get filename
    std::cout << "Enter the name of an existing file: ";
    if (std::string fileName; std::cin >> fileName) {
        // Show fielname again
        std::cout << "\nThe name of your file is: " << fileName << "\n";
        // Try to pen file and check, if it could be opened
        if (std::ofstream myFile(fileName); myFile) {
            // Give positive feedback
            std::cout << "\nFile open is OK\n\n";

            // Define structure
            Loan l1;

            // Get data from user
            std::cout << "Enter principal, months and interest rate" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> l1.principal >> l1.months >> l1.interest;

            // Calculate the monthly rate
            long double monthly = l1.monthlyPayment();

            // Show some statistics
            std::cout << "\n\nMonthly payment will be:  " << monthly << "\n\n Resulting table:\n\n";

            // We want to sum up some values for further statistics
            long double overallInterest = 0.0;
            long double overallRate = 0.0;
            long double overallPaidBack = 0.0;

            // Display header
            myFile << std::right << std::setw(11) << "Month;" << std::setw(16) << "Balance;" << std::setw(11) << "Rate;" <<
                std::setw(11) << "Interest;" << std::setw(11) << "Paid;" << std::setw(16) << "Final\n";

            // Get initial values for calculations
            long double currentBalance = l1.principal;
            unsigned int month = 1;

            // float has always rounding errors. We ignore everything below 0.1
            while (currentBalance > 0.1) {

                // The interes rate for this month
                long double accrued = l1.accrued(currentBalance);
                // Overall, for statistics
                overallInterest += accrued;

                // What is the balance after this month
                long double remainingBalance = l1.remainingBalance(currentBalance);

                // Output values in CSV format
                myFile << std::right << std::setw(10) << month << ";" << std::setw(15) << currentBalance <<
                    ";" << std::setw(10) << monthly << ";" << std::setw(10) << accrued << ";" << std::setw(10) << monthly - accrued
                    << ";" << std::setw(15) << remainingBalance << "\n";

                // Set start point for next month
                currentBalance = remainingBalance;
                // Now we will look at next months
                ++month;
                // Calculate statistical values
                overallRate += monthly;
                overallPaidBack += (monthly - accrued);
            }

            // Show some statistics on sceen
            std::cout << "\nOverall paid interest: " << overallInterest << "\nOverall paid rates:    " << overallRate
                << "\nOverall paid:          " << overallInterest + overallRate
                << "\n\nFor loan of:           " << overallPaidBack << "\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "**** Error. File '" << fileName << "' could not be opened.\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```